# Python upsert returns E11000

Tags: python, mongodb

All

I have about two million records in JSON files that I need to push into a MongoDB. However, some of these records are duplicates and even though I do a update+upsert, it keeps giving me an E11000 Duplicate Key Error. On duplicate match of _id, I want the rest of the body to be updated. If no duplicate, then just insert the record.

My call in Python is:

```
self.collection.update({
    'pid': doc['_id']['pid'],
    'car': doc['_id']['car'],
    'model': doc['_id']['model'],
    'mid': doc['_id']['mid'],
}, doc, upsert=True)
```

*(doc contains _id)

Basically, the `_id` consists of:

```
{
    "pid" : "9778554",
    "car" : "7111115",
    "model" : "9461284",
    "mid" : "9445321"
}
```

The body follows the id. Any suggestions as to what I should do / what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

(I'm using pymongo)

Comment: I see you are missing _id in your update query clause. You are querying by keys that are not part of _id and i don't think it is safe to assume that these fields can be != _id object

Comment: Thank you @aks - should I instead do `self.collection.update({"_id": part["_id"]}, part, upsert=True)` ?

Comment: Another thing you could do, is insert all the records, and then index afterwards and drop duplicates: db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )

Comment: I ended up doing the above (post aks comment) and it worked, but thank you @user602525 for another way to do it.